# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class null

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I tried running my app on a Device but it crashes and stops running. An app is built to run on API level 16 (Android 4.1.1)

I think the problem is coming from the call of setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); method of the MainActivity.java file

but then sorting out where the problem arises is still something I cant figure it out

**Error message from logcat**

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cyanidesystems.savestate/com.cyanidesystems.savestate.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class null



   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class null
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                            at com.cyanidesystems.savestate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1023)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at com.cyanidesystems.savestate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***activity_main.xml file***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/viewColor"
    tools:context="com.cyanidesystems.savestate.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg.tipAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/appAmount"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_hieght"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
         />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tipAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/vertical_hieght"
        android:layout_below="@id/msg.tipAmount"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_hieght"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="$100"
        android:gravity="center"


        />
    <view
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ViewHieght"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ViewHieght"
        android:layout_below="@id/tipAmount"
        android:solidColor="@color/viewColor"
        >

    </view>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:divider="?android:divider"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/percent_amaze"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/vertical_hieght"
            android:text="@string/percent_happy"
            android:background="@color/backgrdColor"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/percent_happy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/vertical_hieght"
            android:text="@string/percent_happy"
            android:background="@color/backgrdColor"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg.totalAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttons"
        android:text="@string/msg.total_Amt"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_hieght"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/totalAmount"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/msg.totalAmount"
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/total_Amt"**strong text**
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java file***

```
package com.cyanidesystems.savestate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

***build.gradle(module app) file***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cyanidesystems.savestate"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'


}
```

Comment: `android:text="@string/total_Amt"**strong text**`. What is `** strong text **`?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

the view tag which you are using should be "View"
Change this-

```
<view
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ViewHieght"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ViewHieght"
    android:layout_below="@id/tipAmount"
    android:solidColor="@color/viewColor"
    />
```

to

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ViewHieght"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ViewHieght"
    android:layout_below="@id/tipAmount"
    android:solidColor="@color/viewColor"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for Your helping hand, I have done the changes but yet it still crashes

Comment: Can you post the logcat message after changing the view tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `<view>` . Its should be `<View>`. Replace your code by.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ViewHieght"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ViewHieght"
    android:layout_below="@id/tipAmount"
    android:solidColor="@color/viewColor"
    >

</View>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have done the changes and the app still crashes